# Mysql: show (Select) field in second table with matching key field in first table

Tags: mysql, select

I'm rather new to mysql, but in former times I created own databases with Cobol.
I created two different records with e.g:

```
1. ID,Cityname
2. ID2,Firstname,Prename,Citycode
```

Content first file:

```
01Boston
02'New York
03Washington
...
```

Content second file:

```
01DoeJohn
02MastersRobin
03JareauJennifer
...
```

Then I took the value of the Cityname instead the Citycode, which was saved in second file records to save data. When I read a (second file) then I read the matching record in first file so that in a list I received:

```
John Doe        New York
Robin Masters   Boston
Jennifer Jareau Washington
```

Now I have two tables in a mysql database. The first contains the Citycode, the second contains the Citycode and the Cityname. I have googled and typed in several tries with 'join' and 'where', but I always get only the Citycode instead of the value to the Citycode,  which is stored in a second table.
Honestly I am confused.

Question is here: could someone pls give me a simple example,
how to select a list with the Cityname in table 2
matching to the Citycode stored in table 1 AND table 2?

I hope, you understand my problem. Goal is to save data and not to repeat the cityname for every record stored in first table.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Forget what you learned in cobol. You need a relationship to JOIN 2 tables in sql and in your case it seems to be citycode.

Comment: Sure I will need 'JOIN', but my tries with 'JOIN' failed. So, what is the correct structure of such a query to show the cityname of the citycode?

Comment: Publish your table definitions (show create table <tablename>) and what you tried with a join and I'll tell you.

Comment: If all fails, post your COBOL code, that would be easier to read than your question above. (Sorry, but i read it twice, and "Honestly I am confused")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some sql statements:

```
CREATE TABLE city (Id INTEGER, CityName VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO city VALUES (1,'Boston');
INSERT INTO city VALUES (2,'New York');
INSERT INTO city VALUES (3,'Washington');

SELECT Id, CityName FROM city;
```

First a table is created, and 3 records are inserted, the SELECT statement shows which records are inserted.

```
CREATE TABLE secondTable (Id INTEGER, secondName VARCHAR(100), CityId INTEGER);

INSERT INTO secondTable(1,'DoeJohn', 2);
INSERT INTO secondTable(2,'MastersRobin', 2);
INSERT INTO secondTable(3,'JareauJennifer', 3);

SELECT Id, secondName, CityId FROM secondTable;
```

Above an example for your second table.

Now you have info in cities in the table `city`, and info on some names in table `secondTable`.

EDIT: added `CityId`.

```
SELECT 
   s.Id,
   s.secondName,
   c.CityName
FROM secondTable s
LEFT JOIN city c ON c.Id = s.CityId;
```

Comment: There is the info that John Doe is living in citycode '1', which is stored with name in the second table. I need a connection between the '1' (citycode in table 1) and the cityname in table 2 matching to the citycode '1' (or '2' or' 3') in table 1.

Comment: Great! After your addition of CityId  and spending many minutes on trial and translating to my original database I got it! It works. Thank you.